# Can a Kenyan apply for a Schengen visa in Tanzania?

Tags: tanzania, schengen-visas, kenyan-citizens

Can a Kenyan citizen can apply for a Schengen visa in Tanzania? He has already purchased his ticket to Italy but, but at the visa centre in Nairobi, there are no appointments available until 3 days after his departure date. In Tanzania, he can submit right now.

He couldn't apply earlier, since his passport was with the Canadian High Commission in Nairobi as his application for a study permit was being examined. 
Given that Kenya and Tanzania are both part of the African Union, does he have a chance that his request can be processed in Tanzania?

Answer (score 2):

He should apply at the consulate for his **place of residence**, regardless of citizenship. There are exceptions for this in hardship cases, but not wanting to wait is not an acceptable exception.